# Delete string in multiple files in directory with cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

:-)

I'm very new to cmd-commands and .bat-stuff, so would be grateful if any of you could help me with a problem.

So...I have a folder with 116 .txt files.
All these .txt files contain lines starting with a "#" and some other lines starting with "---".

I figured that **findstr /v /L /C:"#" test.txt > test2.txt** works in creating a new file without any lines that contain "#"

Now my question, is it possible to write something like findstr /v /L /C:"#" & "---" *.txt > *.txt ?
The goal is that each existing file is overwritten and all lines containing either "#" or "---" are removed.

Glad for any help!

Cheers,
Dyz

Comment: Perhaps, ```%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RV "^[\-#]" "test.txt" 1>"test2.txt"```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the source directoryis a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"

FOR /f "delims=" %%w IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO FINDSTR /v /L /c:"#" /c:"---" "%sourcedir%\%%w">"%sourcedir%\tempfile"&MOVE /y "%sourcedir%\tempfile" "%sourcedir%\%%w" >nul

GOTO :EOF
```

The meat of the matter is the `for/f` line, obviously.

Run `dir /b` to obtain a list of the filenames. `/a-d` excludes directorynames. This list is built in memory first, as the `.txt` files are being replaced - this ensures that the files are only "listed" once.

The `for /f "delims="` reads that list and assigns each line-contents (filename+extension only) to `%%w`. The `delims=` ensures that filenames containing spaces are properly processed.

Then execute the `findstr`, which can take multiple `/c:` arguments to `or` the strings.

[I haven't tried it, but `FINDSTR /v /L "# ---" "%sourcedir%\%%w"` should produce identical processing]

The output of the `findstr` is directed to a temporary filename (I chose to put it in the source directory, but it could be anywhere with any name) and then the temporary file is `move`d over the original with the `1 file moved` message suppressed by a `>nul`.

As always, test first on a copied sample.